# How can I implement double processes protection in android apps?

Tags: android, background-process, application-restart

I found some android app contains 2 processes in background even though I quit the app. After I get into App manager.However I found it hard to kill them when I try to kill the processes. I kill the first one, the second will recreate it; I kill the second one, the first will recreate the other one. 
I finally manage to kill them after I restart my device. But I found the app start the processes soon. I just wanna know how it can restart itself and so hard to kill. I search the whole internet, but I can not find any related solution. Thanks in advance. I just wanna how it work not to develop these annoying apps.

Comment: Where is your code? this explanation is not enough

Answer (score 0):

These processes are processes are probably [Services](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

If you return `START_STICKY` in the `onStartCommand` and it is killed while in the started state, later the system will try to recreate it. So, when you kill the first process, it's not the second process that recreates it but rather the system itself.

> I just wanna how it work not to develop these annoying apps.

If you want your Services to stop when they are killed, simply return `START_NOT_STICKY` in the `onStartCommand`.

Comment: There can be more than one (sticky) service in an app/in a process. Task managers usually kill the process, i.e. they kill _all_ services  as well. Recreation of a service does not work in any case. I faced sometimes issues after the second or third termination. Having two processes might resolve this issue. A _sticky_ service doesn't resolve this reliably.